# peculiar thing about leaving the DateTimeField empty in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

In the model, I set a `DateTimeField`'s `null` and `blank` to be `True`.

When I try to save the model, it will complain about a time format error when setting that field to an empty string but it will be successful when I give it `None`.

```
a.date = ''
a.save() #datetime format error
a.date = None
a.save() #no error this time
```

Why can't Django auto detect that an empty string is `None` when I assign it to a field which already allows `null` and `blank`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTimeFields don't accept strings, they accept Python datetime objects.  Or None, if set to allow blanks.  The empty string isn't a generic Python value for 'no value', so I'm not sure why you would expect it to autoconvert.

Comment: not a big deal actually, it's just not very convenient when I retreived a empty string from request.POST['date'] and I need to convert it to None by my hand, wouldn't it be wonderfull if Django did the job for u

Comment: Are you using a Django form to process the post data?  I can't remember offhand whether the form ends up posting the empty string in the post data or whether it sends no value at all, but a properly configured form will handle this for you.

Comment: No, I didn't use Django form, I guess this is the solution in Django. thank u for remind me

Comment: @castiel Maybe in your case that would be useful, in other cases it might be very confusing. As a general programming principle, doing things explicitly is usually better than doing them implicitly.